# Jquery select all elements further down

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has various select elements.

if i change a select (say the third one down), i want to select all elements (selects) from that point onwards:

i tried:

```
$j(id).nextAll('select').each(function(index) {}
```

but that doesn't work (selects nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `.nextAll` gets the **siblings** that are following the DOM elements in your jQuery object. Most likely your HTML is structured such that there are no sibling select elements.

You should provide more information about what you are trying to do, including accurate sample HTML so we can offer a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
$('select#id option:selected').nextAll().each(function(index) {

   //other options

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following `<SELECT>` elements are sibblings of `$j(id)`:

```
$j(id).nextAll('input:select').each(function(index) { ... })
```

If the following  elements belong to other containers (like `<DIV>` elements):

```
$j(id).parent().nextAll().find('input:select').each(function(index) { ... })
```

Comment: Please don't continue blindly offering random "solutions". If the OP tells us what the HTML looks like we can answer; until then, we can't. Simple as that.

Comment: Those should cover the most common HTML structure scenarios and it was a best effort (mine, at least) with the given information. But I got your point, @Jon.

Comment: @GerardoLima: Fair enough, but about common HTML structures: `TR > TD > SELECT` is angry that it wasn't invited.